# asp.net not able to set Image.Visible to true

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my Default.aspx

```
<div class="well">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSchools" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnContinue" runat="server" Text="Fortsätt" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnContinue_Click" />
<br /><br />
<asp:Image ID="loadingImage" ImageUrl="Images/ajax-loader.gif" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

I set `loadingImage.Visible = false` in `Page_Load`, then i want to show the loadingImage when i hit btnContinue, this is the method i call in Default.aspx.cs, i

```
protected void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadingImage.Visible = true;
    ApiHandeler.getSchoolData();
    Response.Redirect("Overview.aspx");
}
```

However the image is still hidden. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You use `Response.Redirect("Overview.aspx")` to go to a different page after you've changed the visibility to `true`. This modification is pointless if you redirect to a different page. The next time you go to `Default.aspx` it is again invisible. Maybe you want to show a loading image during load, have a loook here:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1308151.aspx

Comment: The ApiHandeler.getSchoolData takes 40sec, i just want to show the loadingImage during that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You perform redirect to another page right after you set the image visibility. The image would be visible if you stayed on the same page. I think you need to set `style="display:none"` and handle the client side onclick like `$("#loadingImage").show();` - in that case you can use simple HTML image `<img src="..." />` without `runat="server"`

Comment: The ApiHandeler.getSchoolData takes 40sec, i just want to show the loadingImage during that time

Comment: You might want to do that using ajax instead of freezing the whole page, but the loading image must be set visible in JS anyway. Also make sure your request doesn't time out. In release configuration I think the default timeout is 90 sec- are you sure it will also be 40 sec with real production data? Timeout can be increased like `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="XX"/>`

Comment: I tried a javascript now. My loading image has style="display:none" in the HTML. Then i change it to img.style.display = "normal"; with a javascript. It' does not work. BUT if i instead set the value to normal in the HTML and change it to none in the javascript, that works. I dont get this...

Comment: I don't think 'normal' is valid value for display. Try setting it to 'inline' or remove the display property completely